# AnyLogic - cannot resolve or is not a field issue

Tags: anylogic

I am adding a new agent and agent population (*Shop/shops*) to AnyLogic model and replicating existing code for *Work/works*. Everything works except *shop* (lowercase). Searched entire software to find where *work* (with lowercase) is defined (in order to do the same for *shop*) to no avail; cannot find anything that would explain why *work* is interpreted and not *shop*. (sorry, I know the question is not framed in a best way - total beginner here). This maybe AnyLogic specific question?

Here is the problem line (*shop* right after p.)

```
p.shop = shops.get( uniform_discr( 0, shops.size()-1 ) );
```

and here is the full code:

```
//setup work locations
for( int i=0; i<works.size(); i++ ) {
    Work w = works.get(i);
    w.X = 540 + 65 * ( i % 3 );
    w.Y = 30 + 50* ( i / 3);
}
for( int i=0; i<shops.size(); i++ ) {
    Shop s = shops.get(i);
    s.X = 750 + 65 * ( i % 3 );
    s.Y = 30 + 50* ( i / 3);
}
//setup families
for( int i=0; i<TotalFamilies; i++ ) {
    //create a Family object
    Family f = add_families();
    //set home location
    f.X = 50 * ( i % 10 );
    f.Y = 40 * ( i / 10 );
    //add family members
    int size = uniform_discr( 2, 5 );
    for( int j=0; j<size; j++ ) {
        //create a person
        Person p = add_people();
        //add to the family
        f.members.add( p );
        p.family = f;
        if (p.old == true) 
        {f.elderHome = true;
        nOld++;};
        //set its home location (in family house)
        p.XHome = f.X + 5 + 5 * ( j % 3 );
        p.YHome = f.Y + 6 - 5 * ( j / 3 ) ;
        p.jumpTo( p.XHome, p.YHome );
        //assign work and shops
        p.shop = shops.get( uniform_discr( 0, shops.size()-1 ) );
        p.work = works.get( uniform_discr( 0, works.size()-1 ) );
    }
} 
//infect three random people at the beginning of the simulation

for( int i=0; i<3; i++ )
    people.get( uniform_discr( people.size()-1 )).
        illness.receiveMessage( "Infection" );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`work` is defined in agent type `Person` as a parameter or variable.

If you error is flagging that for `shop`, it means your agent type `Person` has no variable `shop` (that is of type `Shop`). Add it and the error will go away.

PS: Do some more tutorials and read up on object-oriented programming to understand the basic principles better :)

Comment: Thank you, Benjamin, it solved the problem - spent several hours last night trying to figure out. 

P.S. good point about reading up - trying... among others watched one of your training videos few days ago - very helpful. This is a hobby I am slowly picking up but, having no background in programming, there is so much the middle-aged brain can pick up. Thanks again.

Comment: Great, @mvoltin Please mark the answer as "useful" (up-arrow next to my reply) So others can find it easier in the future :). Welcome to SOF

Comment: It doesn't let me (reputation less than 15) but will do that once I end up posting more. thanks again.